# How i can implement refresh token with custom jwt token generation with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle?

Tags: symfony, jwt, api-platform.com

Currently i create in api platform jwt token with custom symfony controller, provider and encode with JWTEncoderInterface, use authentification come from external api. I have users but not password in my database. How implement refresh token with that system?

security.yml

```
  providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/_(profiler|wdt)
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: true
            stateless: true
            pattern: /authentication_token
```

My authenticator

```
 <?php

namespace App\Security\Guard;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Encoder\JWTEncoderInterface;

use Throwable;

class Authenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private JWTEncoderInterface $jwtEncoder;

    public function __construct(JWTEncoderInterface $jwtEncoder)
    {
        $this->jwtEncoder = $jwtEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * Called on every request to decide if this authenticator should be
     * used for the request. Returning `false` will cause this authenticator
     * to be skipped.
     */
    public function supports(Request $request) : bool
    {
        return $request->headers->has('Authorization Bearer');
    }

    /**
     * Called on every request. Return whatever credentials you want to
     * be passed to getUser() as $credentials.
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request) : string
    {
        return $request->headers->get('Authorization Bearer');
    }

    public function getUser($token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider) : UserInterface
    {
        try {
            $user = $this->jwtEncoder->decode($token);
        } catch(Throwable $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($user['email']);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user) : bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        // on success, let the request continue
        return null;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) : JsonResponse
    {
        $failure = [
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($failure, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null) : JsonResponse
    {
        $data = [
            'message' => 'Authentication Required'
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe() : bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
#[Route('/authentication_token', name: 'security_authentication_token', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function createAuthenticationToken(
        Request $request,
        CreateTokenAuthenticationHandler $createTokenAuthenticationHandler,
        ValidatorInterface $validator
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        $createTokenAuthentication = CreateTokenAuthentication::createFromPayload($request->request->all());
        $errors = $validator->validate($createTokenAuthentication);

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $message[]=  sprintf("Field %s: %s ", $error->getPropertyPath(), $error->getMessage());
            }
            return new JsonResponse($message, JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $token = $createTokenAuthenticationHandler->handle($createTokenAuthentication);

        return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token], JsonResponse::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

My handler where i generate token

```
  public function handle(CreateTokenAuthentication $createTokenAuthentication) : string
    {
        $user = $this->processAuthentication($createTokenAuthentication);

        return $this->jwtEncoder->encode(
            [
                'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                'role' => $user->getRoles()
            ]
        );
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try out this bundle https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle

Comment: Thanks, but in my case i generate token just with JWTEncoderInterfacethis, this lib handle case where not use lexic but just his encoder? @michal

Comment: I don't know answer for this question

Comment: The bundle adds refreshtoken to your response and listens to refresh route to issue next jwt. If you want to do it manually, simply do not register routes and implement your own with extending it's builtin controller. You will also need to generate refreshtoken while generating jwt, generally bundles does it at authentication sucess event in symfony and doesn attach the token. Code is there, whatever way you want to use it depends on usecase.

Comment: Thanks this solve my questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use manual custom refresh token with symfony route in database with token and expiration date.